# Allow visitors to comment with images in a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

In past, in some Pages I used to follow and like, I had the ability to simply upload an image of my own as a comment, with no text. Then, when I created a Page of my own, I wanted to provide such ability to my visitors as well, but I just can't.

I've searched in that super useless Facebook KB and all results said I had to go to **Page Settings** >> **General** >> and check *"Allow visitors to the Page to publish posts"* and, optionally, *"Review posts by other people before they are published to the Page"* as well.

But this doesn't work.

Not only I've seen comments saying this would allow visitors to post **in the Page**, like if they had Administrative/Editorial rights (hence the mentioning of the second option) but when a visitor tries to publish an image as a comment, after the upload and whatever is done during their "Preparing" stage, below the comment box appears:

> Unable to post comment. Try Again

But when clicking this "Try again" link, a modal window says:

> The content you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may have expired, or you may not have permission to view this page.

Since the post or, better saying, the shared link (I don't know if there's any difference) is properly published and available to everyone, I guess it's hitting the third condition.

Does anyone know how to effectively allow a visitor to post an image as a comment, preferably with updated guidelines? I wouldn't mind if all images need approval first, as long as the feature works or, at least, an authorization request does show up in the **Activity Log** (which currently doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on Settings
2. Make sure General is selected
3. Click edit icon on Visitor Posts option
4. Select Allow photo and video posts option